# Android PopupMenu combined with ActionBar in HoneyComb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar, popupmenu

Currently I have the ActionBar setup as follows:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 4").setTabListener(this));
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

When the user clicks on Tab 3, I'd like to have a drop down list of items to choose from.  Currently I've implemented this as follows:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    if (tab.getText() == "Tab 3") {
        PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, tv);
        menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu.getMenu());
        menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                tv.setText(item.getTitle());
                return true;
            }
        });
        menu.show();
    } else {
        tv.setText(tab.getText());
    }
}
```

The issue is that the menu is being aligned to the bottom of the TextView since that's the view it's bound to. Been banging my head on the desk trying to align it to the bottom of "Tab 3".  Any suggestions???

Comment: I haven't tried your code but would PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, tab); not work?

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is a late answer, but I came across your question looking for something else - so maybe this could help someone?*

Couldn't you use a **Popup Window** instead - that way you can set the gravity to the middle of the screen and it would like a regular dialog.

I've used pop up menus only when I need to anchor a menu to the bottom or side,etc of another view (Used it for an action bar item).

*Popup windows can also be displayed as drop down menu* - but they **do not contain menu items**, rather they have **full custom layouts**, so it can be quite powerful.

Here's a link to a mini-tutorial on popup windows:

http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-create-popup-window-in-android.html